# PHP not passing the data array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm working on a site with CodeIgniter and can't figure out why my function is not returning the array, this should be simple.

I did a dump in the model before returning just to see if it was formatted and had the data (which is does). The issue seems to be in the controller the function is not returning the data and in the view properties is null.

What is happening with CI or PHP that might cause this?

```
Controller: 
function galleryManagement()
{
    if (! $this->session->userdata('is_admin'))
    {
        redirect('admin/index');
    }
    else
    {
        /*
        $selectedProperty = $this->input->post('selectedProperty');
        switch ($selectedProperty)
        {
            case "westgate":
                $selectedID = '1';
                break;
            case "prospector436":
                $selectedID = '2';
                break;
            case "prospector437":
                $selectedID = '3';
                break;
            case "prospectorcombo":
                $selectedID = '4';
                break;
            default:
                $selectedID = '-1';
        }
        if ($selectedID != '-1')
        {
        */
            $this->load->model('admin_model');
            $propertyObj = $this->admin_model->getProperties();
            $data['properties'] = $propertyObj;
            $data['propertyID'] = $selectedID;
            $data['galleryObj'] = $this->admin_model->getGallery($selectedProperty);
            //$data['textarea'] = array ( 'name' => 'altText', 'style' => "width: 320px; height: 36px;" );
            $this->load->view('db_site/admin_gallery_view', $data);
        /*
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('admin_model');
            $data['propertiesObj'] = $this->admin_model->getProperties();
            $data['propertyID'] = $selectedID;
            $this->load->view('db_site/admin_gallery_view', $data);
        }
        */
    }
}

Model:
function getProperties()
{
    $this->db->select('property_id, name');
    $this->db->from('property');
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if ($q->num_rows != 0)
    {
        $propertiesObj = $q->result();
        foreach ($propertiesObj as $property)
        {
            $properties[$property->name] = $property->property_id;
        }
        echo "Model Dump: ";
        var_dump($properties);
        return $properties;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

View:
<?php
    var_dump($properties);
    echo form_open('admin/galleryManagement');
    echo "<p>Property: " . form_dropdown('selectedProperty', $properties) . "</p>";        
    echo form_submit('select', 'Select');
?>
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong in that snippet. Is there any code that may impact on $dat (e.g. later you have $data = array('id'=>1); or something like that? If you have edited code, can you post more of the controller?

Comment: Do you see anything in the view for `var_dump($properties);` ?

Comment: I've updated the controller with the whole function. Nothing is over writing the properties key of the $data array. The properties variable in the view is null which means it's not being passed in that's what confused me since I figured I was doing everything correctly.

Comment: so in Model your $properties are correct ?, try to dump $data in Controller, also, try to init properties by hand, just hardcode in controller something like  `$data['properties'] = array('test'=>1,'test1'=>2);` or even simpler one `array(1,2,3);`

Comment: Tried adding $propertyObj = array('1','2','3'); right before the $data['properties'] = $propertyObj; the view still isn't getting the values which is odd. The variable is still undefined in the view.

Comment: $properties isn't a reservered word, but can you try calling it something else, just in case? (Shot in the dark, as the code still looks good...).

Comment: I thought about that before posting my question and checked it with the same results. This has been driving me nuts as it should work.

Comment: So it has something to do with the if ($selectedID != '-1') line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you have used `$properties` which is not passed in the `$data` array of else block from your controller. If you change the controller's else block as below it will work.

```
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $data['properties'] = $this->admin_model->getProperties();
        $data['propertyID'] = $selectedID;
        $this->load->view('db_site/admin_gallery_view', $data);
    }
```

**EDIT**

From your latest edit it looks like you have commented the `else` block i was talking about. You still get the problem ??

Comment: Wow that was it.. my logic was backwards I kept looking at the first if statement when it was really the else section that was being loaded. Now I feel really dumb thought I did a find/replace on all propertiesObj.